# Unclear on setting or getting Java NIO TCP socket buffer size

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a program where i set the buffersize of socket using socketchannel.socket().setBufferSize(100*1024*1024) and OS is ubuntu. And when i tried verifying the value using getBufferSize() i see the value "131071". From few posts i got to know that the value set in setBufferSize() is just a suggestion for the method and not actually picked. I assumed that the value is taken from /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem. But here I see totally different value.

I'm confused. The value mentioned in set method is "104857600", but get method is giving "131071". The value I see in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem is "4096  87380   6291456", where 6291456 is max value which is irrelevant. Could someone Please explain me how this strategy works.

Comment: So you assumed wrong, the maximum is set elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know from where the value is picked and how it actually works

Comment: The value "131071" is picked from /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max but not tcp_rmem. But i'm not sure what is the difference between these two.

Comment: There's another issue before that. You won't get any benefit from a buffer size > 64k unless it is set before connecting or accepting. And not all that much benefit afterwards frankly.

Comment: Hmm. I observed that. Thanks for your valuable response.